# Is there an Android native library for XMPP client?

Tags: java, android, ejabberd, smack, asmack

I am working on XMPP client for Android, we have establish our Ejabberd server(2.1.11) on ubuntu 14.04.

For implementing XMPP android client i have used patched version of [java smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/) called [aSmack](https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack) and it is great as you have to include asmack.XXX.jar in your android project lib folder and write some code which is easy available on INTERNET,i want to thank all developer for their awesome work.

Here

> I am curious what kind of mechanism aSmack using to communicate with
>   XMPP server

But as per our client requirement i cant use any 3'rd party library for implementing Xmpp client in android[means i cant use aSmack :-( ]

> 1>>. Is there any Android native library available for implementing xmpp client?

Thanks in advance!!!!!!

Comment: smack is open source : https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack.git  you could persuade your client to use it after going through an extensive code review?

Comment: I disagree with people who are marking this question as off-topic. There is a absolutely clear question here, which is "Is there any Android native library available for implementing xmpp client?" and also an unquestionable (till nowadays) answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If with 'Android native library' you mean 'an API from the standard Android SDK' then no, there is not such native library. To reach that requirement you'll have to write your own XMPP API.

I advice you to explain your contractor about free software licenses and ask him to change that requirement.

Comment: thank you vary much for your answer,as you said mention u have to write my own xmpp api ,Is there any website or document which explains the data flow from android to xmpp server and how many levels would be there?

Comment: You can check the XMPP protocol stack [here](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-protocols/xmpp-core/). This contains the basic hand-shake to chat. Many times we want to use the extensions to improve the software such as Multiuser Chat or XMPP Over BOSH. In this case, here is a list of available extensions and their data flow: http://xmpp.org/xmpp-protocols/xmpp-extensions/ . You can also take a look at http://xmpp.org for more info. I'm have to say that implement that stack will not be a quick task.